Strawberry GraphQL Federation: TypeError: Cannot convert value to AST: ['id']
Full disclosure: first time Strawberry user, new to Python, but not new to GraphQL and federation.
I followed https://strawberry.rocks/docs/guides/federation with Vendor and Product as classes instead of Book and Review... coming from vendor and product subgraphs. The product subgraph stores references to vendors (one per product)...
I also followed the example in https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphos/reference/federation/directives after the above didn't work directly, to be more explicit. The issue is coming from the product service with the following snippet being relevant: https://play.strawberry.rocks/?gist=bc4d6aafc842a0adb4ca9f0573d91cb0
@strawberry.type(
    directives=[
        Key(fields=["id"]),  # <------- NOTE 2
    ]
)
class Vendor:
    id: strawberry.ID


def get_product_origin_vendor(root: "Product") -> Vendor:
    return Vendor(id=root.vendor_id)


@strawberry_django.type(
    models.Product,
    description="...",
    filters=ProductFilter,
    pagination=True,
    directives=[Key(fields="id")]
)
class Product:
    id: strawberry.ID
    vendor_id: strawberry.Private[strawberry.ID]
    vendor: Vendor = strawberry.field(
        resolver=get_product_vendor,
        directives=[Provides(fields=["id"])]  # <------- NOTE 1
    )

If I don't provide the directives (see notes 1 and 2), rover expectedly complains about the id not being shared and conflicting.
If I add those directives, I get:
  ...
  File "/.../strawberry/printer/ast_from_value.py", line 84, in ast_from_leaf_type
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Cannot convert value to AST: ['id'].

... when rover calls for { _service { sdl }}.
I toyed with field names in these directives and the Provides directive (note 1) is the first to fail if both are present.
What am I doing wrong ... or not doing?
P.S. I have also looked at https://github.com/strawberry-graphql/strawberry-django/issues/59 ... but I don't think that's relevant (any more). (edited)
